# ng-Route Doesnot showing template URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, ngroute

app.js

```
app.config(function($routeProvider)
       {
$routeProvider
.when('/',{
    templateUrl:'app/views/navigation/blogs.html',
    controller:'logincontroller'
})
.when('/post',{
    templateUrl:'app/views/navigation/post.html',
    controller:'logincontroller'
})
.when('/edit',{
    templateUrl:'app/views/navigation/edit.html',
    controller:'logincontroller'
})
.when('/update',{
    templateUrl:'app/views/navigation/update.html',
    controller:'logincontroller'
})
.when('/blogs',{
    templateUrl:'app/views/navigation/blogs.html',
    controller:'logincontroller'
})
.otherwise({redirectTo:'/edit'});
```

});

my html:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#/edit"> Edit details</a>
          </li>
          <li ><a href="#/"></i> Post a blogs</a>
          </li>
          <li><a  href="#/blogs"> blogs</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
```

I am trying to fix a bug in this code i wrote a long time ago,however im clueless what is wrong here.The app only loads default root route and display blogs.html inside ng-view.for every other link pressed in navigation, it still loads the root route.

Comment: Try removing '/' from your href, <li><a href="#edit"> Edit details</a>

Comment: `<a href="#/post"></i> Post a blogs</a>` Just change it once and check.. If u dont want navigation then give ``<a href=" ">`